# html/css: element size is calculated top-down or bottom-up?

Tags: html, css

html/css: element size is calculated top-down or bottom-up? e.g.

```
.box {
   width: 100%;
   overflow: visible;
}
.container {
   width: fit-content;
}
pre {
   overflow: auto;
}

<div class="box">
   <div class="container">
      <pre>
      line1-------------------VeryLong
      line2-------------------VeryLong
      </pre>
   </div>
</div>
```

What is the container width?

For top-down, it is 100%, and pre has scroll.

For bottom-up, the pre does not have scroll, and the container width is the same as the pre width.

From my experiments, it is bottom-up: the pre does not have scroll.

The only way to make the pre element scroll is to set the container width to be a fixed width like 500px (100% not working).

How to make the pre element scroll without setting a fixed width?

Comment: Have you try something like "width: 100vw;" for class container's width?